# Strange behaviour on select query on date columns

Tags: java, select, jdbc, ojdbc

A strange behaviour of select query just came up on my way while im doing a task for the uni.Im pulling data from a table i got on my oracle db.

```
selectString = "select * from reservation";
prestatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectString);
rs = prestatement.executeQuery(selectString);
while (rs.next()) {
    String rdate = rs.getString("reservdate").substring(0, 10);
    jComboBox1.addItem(rdate);
//....
//....etc..
```

The thing is that what is displayed on my combo box is a think like '1999-10-10'
After that i have to pull some data where i must select the ones with the date of the selected item on the combo box.Well there's my problem.

```
String x = String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
selectString="select * from reservation where reservdate='"+x+"'";
//...etc..
```

After i run that im getting an sql exception with message : Message: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
I searched a little bit the web and found that if i run this select query everything works fine

```
selectString="select * from reservation where reservdate='10-OCT-99'";
```

So my question is, what is the best way to make this work.I mean should i try edit all the dates from combo box to this format? or im doing something wrong all the way and should change that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1- Override your related class' (whatever object that getSelectedItem returns, in this particular case its already a String and you may not need that String.valueOf() call) toString method to achieve the needed format of yours. (Kind of bad to do)

2- Let Oracle DB handle it with its TO_DATE function (Kind of a better practice to do)

"TO_DATE(yourDateString,dateFormat)"

```
String date = String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
selectString="select * from reservation where reservdate= TO_DATE('" + date + "','DD-MON-YY')";
```

And to prevent SQL injections, using the latter approach with a PreparedStatement would look like this:

```
String date = String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());    
String selectString="select * from reservation where reservdate= TO_DATE(?,'DD-MON-YY')";
PreparedStatement preStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectString);
preStatement.setString(1,date);
ResultSet rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

[Official Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

Comment: im getting a :Message: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated.

Comment: Now i am back where i  started: Message: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: same thing..i also tried mm instead of mon but still cant get it right..

Comment: found a solution: selectString="select * from reservation where reservdate=TO_DATE('" + x + "','YYYY-MM-DD')"; Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: well you are welcome but isn't it actually what I proposed to do? :)

Comment: oh wow. the main point was to inform you about oracle's to_date function which you can use to manipulate your date strings, the formatting of the date is up to your needs mine was just an example. but anyway, no need to argue about it. glad it helped.